# JSReport error "This socket is closed" occurs when run in background RHEL

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, npm, jsreport

I have a issue in the JSReport www.jsreport.net.

If I start npm start --production in the background, it works, but if I exit this session, an error occurs:

```
Error occured - This socket is closed.
Stak - Error: This socket is closed.
    at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:638:19)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:226:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:216:5)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:183:11)
    at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:616:40)
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

To start jsreport in the background on linux, I use

```
nohup npm start --production > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

To start jsreport in the background and autostart on reboot

```
# install pm2
sudo npm install pm2 -g

# start pm2 daemon running jsreport
sudo pm2 start npm -- start --production

# create startup script for running jsreport after boot
sudo pm2 startup
sudo pm2 save
```